# DB2, Stored Procedures that are refering to a table name

Tags: db2, procedure, refer

In DB2 - Is there any SQL statement, when I execute, will return a list of Stored Procedures that are referring to a table name.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: Version : DB2 v9.5.0.8

Comment: ...note that any list returned will only be correct if you haven't implemented procedures a certain way; for example, picking a table out of syscat to query will make references opaque...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In db2 how to find all the Stored Procedures having a given text in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087281/in-db2-how-to-find-all-the-stored-procedures-having-a-given-text-in-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the catalog view SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP for that:

`select specificname, routineschema from syscat.routinedep where btype='F' and bschema='yourschema' and bname='yourtable'`

This will return all routines (incl. stored procedures) dependent on that referenced table identified by yourschema.yourtable

Answer (score 1):

There is a catalog view `SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP`:

```
SELECT R.ROUTINESCHEMA, R.ROUTINENAME 
FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP D, SYSCAT.ROUTINES R
WHERE D.ROUTINESCHEMA = R.ROUTINESCHEMA AND D.SPECIFICNAME = R.SPECIFICNAME 
AND D.BTYPE IN ('T','V','A') 
AND D.BSCHEMA = 'MYTABLESCHEMA' AND D.BNAME = 'MYTABLENAME'
```

Keep in mind that tables referenced by dynamic SQL will not appear in `SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP`.