# How to find all objects that query a table in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

I want to find all objects (Stored Procedures, views, etc) that make queries to each table in DB2 hosted in IBM iSeries. Is there a way to track this over a time period say 1 month.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In db2 how to find all the Stored Procedures having a given text in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087281/in-db2-how-to-find-all-the-stored-procedures-having-a-given-text-in-it)

Comment: Although note that that can't find dynamic SQL queries.  There's ways to set up performance monitoring for specific table that will yield queries run against them, but if you enable it globally it's going to make performance tank.

Comment: You can journal a table and the journal will tell all the objects that have used the table over time.  Turning journaling on for all tables probably isn't such a bad idea as it once seemed.  Journaling adds two plus times IO and disk space cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the plan cache. This is not exactly what you are asking for, but I believe it should be able to give you the information you need. The plan cache is a cache of all SQL statements that have been executed, along with performance in formation about them. You can filter the plan cache by a number of things, including the run date, and objects referenced.

This is an interactive tool that is available in System i Navigator, or more recently in iACS. In iACS, you can search the plan cache by:

1. Navigate to Database -> SQL Performance Center.
2. Under the `Plan Cache` tab, click the `Show Statements` button.

The resulting dialog has filters on the left, and statements on the right sorted by total  (cumulative) processing time in descending order. As long as you don't need some automated task to handle your queries, and you are not looking for the programs involved, then this should give you the information you are looking for.

If you are looking for the program that references a given table, you can use the command `DSPPGMREF`. This command allows you to capture (in a file in your case) all the objects referenced by a given program. As long as you run the command over all libraries that contain programs you are interested in, then you can query the output table to find every program that references a given table (except dynamic queries).